# Html css hover alternative

Tags: html, css

The :hover selector style links on mouse-over. I want when i click then show elements not with mouse - over . What hover alternative i should use..`#cssmenu li:hover ul{
        display:block;
        }`

Comment: you can try jQuery for this that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle for demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dineshswami/nXGYc/

HTML:

```
<ul id="cssmenu">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2
        <ul>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#cssmenu ul{
display:none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("bang");
    $("#cssmenu li").click(function () {
        alert("bang bang");
        $("#cssmenu li ul").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: where i should write this jQuery? I used jsp

Comment: I have just mention the working demo in the post. I have just created the fiddle for demo purpose and extra enhancement you requirement you have to tweak the code. The alert are just for the purpose of showing that events are working fine.

Comment: You have to embed the the jquery library in your head tag of html page, you can download from http://jquery.com/download/ or from cdn version from here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach that uses HTML and CSS only is based on the `:target` pseudo-class:

```
<style>
#cssmenu li ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu :target ul  {
  display: block;
}
 li:hover ul { display:block; }
</style>
<h1>menu with target</h1>
<ul id="cssmenu">
    <li><a id=sub1 href=#sub1>submenu 1
        <ul>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
        </ul></a>
    </li>
    <li><a id=sub2 href=#sub2>submenu 2
        <ul>
            <li>item A</li>
            <li>item B</li>
            <li>item C</li>
        </ul></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/aV5HE/)

However, the `:target` pseudo-class is not supported by IE 8 and older, so if you wish to cover them as well, you need to use some JavaScript polyfill such as [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) or Selectivizr (or use an entirely JavaScript-based approach).